# Usage limits for Google Maps Distance API from Client server app

Tags: google-maps-api-3

We provide a traditional Client Server software package.

We want to build in a feature that will allow us pass 2 addresses to the Google Maps Distance API and get a time back to travel between the 2 addresses.

2 Questions:

1. Would each request be ONE of the 2500 free requests per day?
2. Could each of my customers get their own API Key so that they would
   have their own 2500 requests per day?

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow. The way it works here is that you need to include some code in the question to show that you have put some efforts and you need help. Members here will not write the code for you.

Comment: In this case he is asking about the limitations the Google free API keys, so no code is involved (well, at one moment some code have to be involved but he is not asking about it).

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes if it is using your API key or client ID then that would be one of your requests for the 24 hour period.
2. If you mean the client is passing their own API key to the server for each request. I think you could technically do this, but I think it would violate the google terms of service - https://developers.google.com/maps/terms. If you mean you would provision a server instance for each client with their own API key, then I believe that would be acceptable. There may also be some applicable terms of use in regards to how this API key is provided.